# Drop parent table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, constraints, parent-child

I've created two simple tables to ilustrate this question.

```
CREATE TABLE `child` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `father_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_22B354292055B9A2` (`father_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

CREATE TABLE `father` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

ALTER TABLE `child`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `child_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`father_id`) REFERENCES `father` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Imagine that there are rows in the child table linked to the father table through the foreign key.

If I delete a row in the father table that has rows linked to it in the child table, I can delete it anyway because I have "ON DELETE CASCADE" activated.

The problem is that if I try to drop the father table, even if there are no rows neither on the father table nor on the child table, I get the following error message (in phpmyadmin):

```
#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I tried this command:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

But the same error message appears.

I could delete the whole database and create it again, but I don't want to do that if there is another solution (like ON DELETE CASCADE for the rows).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the constraint itself.  alter table child drop foreign key child_ibfk_1;

Comment: The reason I want to know how to do this only with the `DROP TABLE  father` command, is because I want to use this command from Symfony2:

  `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load`

Which flushes the database first before loading data. But it gives me the same error as phpmyadmin because of the same reasons (the only difference is that the Symfony2 command uses truncate table). I certainly could drop the foreign key in the child table, but I was wondering if there is an alternative solution that does it automatically, like the ON DELETE CASCADE solution for the rows.

Comment: I don't believe there is any such functionality, at least not that I've run across.  Deleting rows is a change to data, whereas dropping a table is a change to schema.